Configuring CORS and XSRF for streamlit using Azure App Service Web App
My python web app is using streamlit as a frontend and is deployed on Azure App Services.
When using the st.file_uploader component, locally everything works fine. When deployed, however, a 403 error pops up on file upload. The issue comes from CORS / XSRF checks and only happened in one of the recent streamlit releases (1.29 or 1.30 most likely).
It is possible to disable these checks in the streamlit server, either via config.toml or this startup command:
python3.10 -m streamlit run /home/site/wwwroot/app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0 --server.enableXsrfProtection=false --server.enableCORS=false

The streamlit documentation recommends to turn the checks back on and fix the startup command like this:
python3.10 -m streamlit run /home/site/wwwroot/app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0 --browser.serverPort 443 --browser.serverAddress=https://example-app.azurewebsites.net

Unfortunately, the check fails with all possible combinations that I came up with for browser.serverPort and browser.serverAddress.
One issue might be, that streamlit always prepends http to browser.serverAddress (can be seen in the Azure Log stream), but the app loads regardless of that.
The port is another unknown. I did test port 80 as well, which doesn't connect to the app at all.
Does anyone have experience with these settings in the Azure App Service context?

I tried below code and settings in order to upload a file from my local machine to Azure web app via streamlit successfully:-
My app.py:-
import streamlit as st
import os

def main():
    st.title("File Uploader")
    
    # File uploader
    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file", type=['csv', 'txt'])
    
    if uploaded_file is not None:
        # Save the uploaded file
        with open(os.path.join("streamlit", uploaded_file.name), "wb") as f:
            f.write(uploaded_file.getbuffer())
        st.success("File uploaded successfully!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

In my streamlit code, I am adding my csv file inside streamlit directory, You can add your folder name instead of streamlit where your file exists:-
with open(os.path.join("streamlit", uploaded_file.name), "wb")

Here's my folder structure:-

requirements.txt:-
streamlit

In order for streamlit app to load, Create your Azure Web app with Python version above 3.10 and use B1 SKU.

Also, add the below startup command to load the streamlit app successfully:-
python -m streamlit run app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0


Output:-



Thanks for your detailed answer. This is exactly what we have done so far, but it stopped working due to CORS safety measures, which is what I tried to describe in the question. The streamlit apps are running fine and can also upload files on older streamlit versions (I think <1.30 or <1.29).

did you add the azure web app url in the CORS of Azure Web app?

Yes, I tried many different combinations of protocols, ports, IP addresses and domains (I guess https://*.azurewebsites.net:443 should be the correct entry), but no change in behavior, still get the AxiosError 403.
